# What are the disadvatages of applying migrations at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

Excerpt from [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/):

> Some apps may want to apply migrations at runtime during startup or
>   first run. Do this using the Migrate() method.
>
> `myDbContext.Database.Migrate();`
>
> **Warning**
>
> This approach isn't for everyone. While it's great for apps with a
>   local database, most applications will require more robust deployment
>   strategy like generating SQL scripts.

The main benefit of this approach seems to be keeping the deployment process simple. 
The documentation states that this will not be sufficient for most apps. Why not?

What are the disadvatages of applying migrations at runtime?

Comment: You can’t babysit query plans. Which change as data increases. Or across MySQL, PostgreSQL, sql server, etc...if your app supports multiple db techs. Security. App often restricted from altering tables or creating tables. This involves having elevated permissions. Which isn’t good if your app gets compromised. Little tommy tables.

Comment: I don't see disadvantages of this, only if you do big mistakes. For example, if you remove a column from a table, you must know that all data from production will be remove at deployment and restart of your api.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons:

- Migrations may cause the database to lose data.
- You may work on an obsolete branch.
- Migrations may fail.
- Good app design doesn't create or delete tables.

Migrations may cause your database to lose data. Like your migration may drop some table. Not all environments expect to do that. This may be safe in your development environment but very dangerous in the production environment. This is the main reason why some applications do not migrate automatically.

Now we usually code with git or other version control tools. Switching branches and collaborate with others is more simple. But typically our database doesn't switch branch with your code. If you switched to another branch and just run the application, the migrations may ruin your database and hard for you to recover.

Migrations may fail because of connection reasons or data conflict. If you migrate the database automatically, you will not be warned and this is dangerous because a bigger problem will occur while your service is online.

In one word: **Applying migration is a dangerous action**. Unless you can ensure everything is fine or you are not suggested to automatically update the database.